# A license that gives you credit to the code forever with minor changes

Tags: license-recommendation, license, website

I'm new to licensing and open source as a whole, so please be patient with me.

Let's say I have created an organization on Github that's called "Organization X", under that organization I created a repository that's called "App X" (it's an open source project and basically, I call it a product).

For that product, I'm looking for a license that does the following:

1. You're free to use the code inside the project, as far as:

   1. You give credit to the whole organization basically in the format of "Lines from 20 to 100 have been taken from App X that's under Organization X." while also putting the Organization's and product's logo (that are clearly visible to everyone). Also if person Y takes the same code that person X took from Organization X (my organization), they should give credit to Organization X.
   2. You can't take the whole product and republish (aka the source code) it. You can only take minor parts to use in your project, or product under whatever organization or company (basically anywhere). I mean as far as you do some *significant* edits, it's OK to use the source code.
   3. You can't sell it in anyway or form (basically gain income from it in anyway). The whole product is free for everyone therefore you can't sell it.
   4. You can't use the code in private projects, your project can be personal or even public to the whole planet but no private or closed-source projects. I mean it should be open-source too.
2. You can't use the organization's logo or product's logo in anyway. You should indicate that this is a different project and no relation between the two.

I clearly searched for such licenses but couldn't find anything specific. Also, I'm wondering if someone violated any of the above rules what will happen or what should I do in this case?

Also is there anything important you think I missed? To summarize, "I want people to be able to use the source code while always giving credit, not gaining any income from it, and making it open source with an indication that there's no relation between them and my organization. They can't republish the whole source code again unless making some significant edits".

I think this is the right site to ask such a question, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Some of your other conditions probably make this not open source as well, but (3) is cut and dried.

Comment: Others have noted that such a license is not FLOSS so unfortunately, giving a robust recommendation isn't on-topic here (and is practically difficult for most community members because we don't keep a good index of commercial-forbidding licenses). I will also add that requiring your logo whenever your code is used may put your logo trademark in **serious jeopardy**. That could attach your mark to any project that used any of your code in any context, and dilute your mark, if you don't approve each use (either manually or via a specific policy). Definitely consult a trademark lawyer first.

Comment: @apsillers Oh, I don't mind the logo, let's just say I want the organization's name. Also, it's not really a trademark honestly just non-profit organization (nothing official). But actually, the whole project is open-source, I just wanted it to be a limited one. The question Philip Kendall doesn't really answer the question yet I wanted a license that meets criteria provided.

Comment: @PhilipKendall What do you mean by "cut and dried"? I just wanted no one to make any income from it, because I don't do that. Or at least I'm free to but they're not.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour That your requirement to prevent people selling it makes it absolutely 100% definitely not an open source license [as defined by the scope of this site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What you describe is definitely too restrictive for open source. It's probably best to ask a lawyer to draft a special contract for this. I'm not sure some of the restrictions are legally possible -- for example, giving me a license to use your software but then preventing me from using it in a personal project (which I'm not redistributing) seems strange. Most software licenses work by assigning conditions under which redistribution is permitted (i.e. giving redistribution permission). This works legally because, normally, redistribution is forbidden under Copyright law without permission.